# Hosting mixed static and dynamic content efficiently on AWS at the same domain for a single page website

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can anyone point me to information on setting up a single-page site effectively using AWS.

I'd like HTML, JS, and CSS requests to be served quickly since they're static files that will change very infrequently - good for a CDN. But, JSON requests are dynamic and so they need to go to an application server. I could split them into subdomains, but then I have to do some stuff in JS I'd like to avoid.

Is there a way I can have my domain point somewhere that has a very quick differentiation between types of requests, serving HTML/JS/CSS like a CDN and passing JSON requests further, without becoming a bottleneck? In general, is there a recommended way to routing within AWS by path/request type on the same domain - like an ELB but passing based on criteria to different places that might have ELBs in front of them?

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways to do this.

## Split domain

Use a subdomain like cdn.domain.com for a S3 bucket that is served through CloudFront (or any CDN of your choice). Make domain.com point to your website (likely, to your ELB).

## Cache-control

Make domain.com point to your website (likely, to your ELB). Have your server send static files with an appropriate cache-control header (for instance, `cache-control: max-age=2592000`. That's one month).